# Automatic String to Number conversion in Python

Tags: python, casting

I am trying to compare two lists of string in python. Some of the strings are numbers however I don't want to use it as number, only for string comparison.

I read the string from a file and put them on a list like this:

```
def main():
    inputFileName = 'BateCarteira.csv'
    inputFile = open(inputFileName, "r")

    bankNumbers = []

    for line in inputFile:
        values = line[0:len(line)-1].split(';');

        if (len(values[0]) > 3):
            bankNumbers.append(''+values[0])
```

However, when I try to print the number, it prints like:

1,20091E+11

The code for the printing:

```
    print 'not in the list: ' + bankNumber
    outputFile.write(bankNumber + '-')
```

What can I do so python never casts the string to an int?

sorry for my english :D

Comment: What is does the csv file have for the value that is converted to 1,20091E+11? Sounds like you have a value bigger than an Int and it is being turned into a Float.

Comment: If you change the code for printing like so:

`print 'not in the list: ' + bankNumber, type(bankNumber)`

It will print the type of the bankNumber value.  I predict it will print "str", showing you that it is in fact a string type; and I predict that if you look in the CSV file, you will see the string "1,20091E+11".  Not only does Python never convert a string to a float without asking you, but that is not the format I would expect Python to use when printing a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python never transforms a string to a number, unless you try something like:

```
s = "1.2"
a = float(s)
```

So I guess that your .csv file has the string "1,20091E+11" inside it. Also notice that the decimal point is a coma. So, if you tried to convert it to a float, the transformation would fail.

Comment: Sounds like this is right. I suspect the input file has unexpected values. Some locales like German and French use , for . in numbers.

Comment: You may want to look at the standard "locale" library module.

Comment: Yeah, that was right...

the atof function also helps.

the language is portuguese.

Answer (score 2):

You need the locale module to read numbers in the locale format (i.e with decimal comma that's used in (most) parts of Europe).

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
f = locale.atof("1,20091E+11")
```